# Smoke/Flame clipping trough the object in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

Smoke/flame in eevee clips trough the object.

I have tried higher divisions on domain, 4-6 timesteps, volumetric lighting and shadow samples at 256, volumetric tile size is 2px, volumetric clipping is 0.1-1000m.

In cycles it works great, but whole scene with everything enabled would take weeks or even months to render.

This is very simplified version what I mean.

[image: This is very simplified version what i am meaning]

Thank you!